# firing onsen's setMainPage in onclick using variable from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick, angularjs-ng-repeat, onsen-ui

i want to make my Onsen UI splitView app to set the main page with a certain page based on a variable it got from the clicked item in a list. the list is generated by ng-repeat.

i have searched about `ng-repeat` and `ng-click`, but none give what i am expected/ or maybe it is me that not understand them.

here's my code :

### HTML

```
<ons-split-view 
 var="splitView"
 secondary-page="secondary.html" 
 main-page="main1.html" 
 main-page-width="60%" >
</ons-split-view>

<ons-template id="main1.html" >
    <ons-page ng-controller="ApkController as page">
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">List of page</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            <ons-list>
                <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-repeat="content in page.contents" onclick="splitView.setMainPage(content.name'.html');">{{content.number}}. {{content.name}}</ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
 </ons-template>

<ons-template id="secondary.html">
    <ons-page style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" ><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-lg" style="color: #666"></i> Back</span></div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <tr >
                <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">Please choose the page you want </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ons-page>
 </ons-template>

<ons-template id="page1.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center"> page 1</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-button onclick="splitView.setMainPage('main1.html')">click</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="page2.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center"> page 2</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-button onclick="splitView.setMainPage('main1.html');">click</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="page3.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center"> page 3</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-button onclick="splitView.setMainPage('main1.html')">click</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

### Javascript

```
ons.bootstrap().controller('ApkController', function () {
    this.contents = something;
});

var something = [
{
    number : '78',
    name : 'page1',            
},
{
    number : '79',
    name : 'page2',
},
{
    number : '80',
    name : 'page3',
}];
```

and here's the above code in codepen.io : http://codepen.io/fadynoor/pen/GJJMLx

**the problem** is i don't know how to insert my `content.name` in the `setMainPage()` so it could work as i'm expected.

i'm pretty new to onsen and angular. any suggestions?

p.s. : it's my first question in this forum. so, sorry if i make mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make following changes and your code should work

```
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-repeat="content in page.contents" ng-click="showContent( content)">{{content.number}}. {{content.name}}</ons-list-item>
```

Javascript controller should look like this

```
ons.bootstrap().controller('ApkController', function ($scope) {
  this.contents = something;

  $scope.showContent = function(content){
    splitView.setMainPage(content.name + ".html");

  };
});
```

Comment: thanks, CuriousMind. you're a savior. i don't have any idea that a function from one js could be put into another js file